# F.54: If you capture this, capture all variables explicitly (no default capture)

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

Slightly got confused after reading this  [Cppcore Guideline F.54](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f54-if-you-capture-this-capture-all-variables-explicitly-no-default-capture)

Regarding the lambda capture

> "Writing [=] in a member function appears to capture by value, but
>   actually captures data members by reference "

Example

```
class My_class {
    int x = 0;
    // ...

    void f() {
        int i = 0;
        // ...

        auto lambda = [=]{ use(i, x); };   // BAD: "looks like" copy/value capture
        // [&] has identical semantics and copies the this pointer under the current rules
        // [=,this] and [&,this] are not much better, and confusing

        x = 42;
        lambda(); // calls use(42);
        x = 43;
        lambda(); // calls use(43);

        // ...

        auto lambda2 = [i, this]{ use(i, x); }; // ok, most explicit and least confusing

        // ...
    }
};
```

Why this is treated as bad

```
auto lambda = [=]{ use(i, x); };
```

and the below one as good practice

```
auto lambda2 = [i, this]{ use(i, x); };
```

I tried with the example but didn't see any difference.May be I didn't understand the statements properly

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class My_class {
public:
    int x = 0;
    // ...

    void f() {
        int i = 0;
        // ...

        auto lambda = [=]{ cout<<i<<x<<endl; };   // BAD: "looks like" copy/value capture
        // [&] has identical semantics and copies the this pointer under the current rules
        // [=,this] and [&,this] are not much better, and confusing

        x = 42;
        lambda(); // calls use(42);
        x = 43;
        lambda(); // calls use(43);

        // ...

        auto lambda2 = [i, this]{ cout<<i<<x<<endl; }; // ok, most explicit and least confusing

        lambda2();
    }
};

int main()
    {
        My_class val;
        val.f();
    }
```

Output

```
042
043
043
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Any direction, guideline or explanation with example will be helpful

> Edit
>
> After few explanation(see the answers below) 
>    created a new example to demonstrate the
>   behaviour

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class My_class {
public:
    int x = 0;
    // ...

    void f() {
        int i = 0;
        // ...

        auto lambda = [=]{ cout<<i<<x<<endl; x=10; };   // BAD: "looks like" copy/value capture
        // [&] has identical semantics and copies the this pointer under the current rules
        // [=,this] and [&,this] are not much better, and confusing


        x = 42;
        lambda(); // calls use(42);
        cout<<"value of x is "<<x<<endl;


        x = 43;
        lambda(); // calls use(43);

        // ...

        auto lambda2 = [i, this]{ cout<<i<<x<<endl; }; // ok, most explicit and least confusing
        lambda2();
    }
};

int main()
    {
        My_class val;
        val.f();
    }
```

Output

```
042
value of x is 10
043
010
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Even though capture by value this changes the outer x value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Writing [=] in a member function appears to capture by value, but actually captures data members by reference "

The quote says it all, Writing [=] in a member function appears to capture by value, but actually captures data members by reference.

One of the big names once said that it is a good thing if you don´t have to be smart. Meaning you should be explicit, and use the language to clearly express what you want to happen.

Default capture captures the variables in the local scope. this->x is not in scope but this is in scope. Thus x is not captured but this is. But you may very well use a sole x to denote this->x.

So despite the fact that you ordered capture by value you get capture by reference. That kind of things requires you to read carefully and concentrated and might catch unaware programmers by surprise.

I changed the example a little bit and added some more alternatives.

#### [=]

potemkin capture, promises to capture **everything** by value, yields capture by reference for all class members because of this->

#### [i,this]

more explicit capture, promises to capture i and **this** by value thus the level of concentration required to see that this->x will be a by reference capture is reduced.

I would suggest using **this->x** in the body instead of x to have that absolutely clear.

#### [=, my_copy_of_x = x]

Init capture syntax allows to explicitly capture x by value or reference whatever is wanted. &my_copy_of_x = x would yield reference capture

#### [=,my_copy_of_x = this->x]

The same just a little bit more verbose. Clearly states that x is a member and not a local variable.

#### [my_i = i, my_copy_of_x = this->x]

That of course also works for local variable i

```
using namespace std;

class My_class {
public:
    int x = 0;
    
    void f() {
        int i = 0;
        x = 42;
        
        auto lambda1 = [=]{ cout << i << " " << x << endl; };
        auto lambda2 = [i,this]{ cout << i << " " << x <<endl; };
        auto lambda3 = [=,my_copy_of_x = x]{  cout<<i<<" "<< x << " " << my_copy_of_x << endl;  };
        auto lambda4 = [=,my_copy_of_x = this->x]{ cout<<i<<" "<< x << " " << my_copy_of_x << endl; };
        auto lambda5 = [my_i = i, my_copy_of_x = this->x]{ cout << my_i << "    " << my_copy_of_x<<endl;; };
        
        lambda1(); lambda2(); lambda3(); lambda4(); lambda5();
        x = 43;
        std::cout << "\nx changed\n\n";
        lambda1(); lambda2(); lambda3(); lambda4(); lambda5();
    }
};

int main()
{
    My_class val;
    val.f();
}

0 42
0 42
0 42 42
0 42 42
0    42

x changed

0 43
0 43
0 43 42
0 43 42
0    42
```

Comment: That was very detailed explanantion

Comment: After a year of c++, I finally understand how to capture, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> "Writing [=] in a member function appears to capture by value, but
>   actually captures data members by reference "

Because data members cannot be captured. What got captured is `this`.

Even `this` is captured by copy, you can still modify all members `this` as if the members are captured by reference, are they are all accessed through the `this` pointer which is what really got captured.

By using `auto lambda2 = [i, this]{ use(i, x); };`, you make it clear that `x` is not captured, but `this` is.

Comment: Thanks for long and most of the books explains [=]  capture by value and [&] capture by reference.

Comment: Even though it is capture by value by the use of this we can change member variables value?

Comment: @HariomSingh `this` is a pointer. The pointer is pointer is captured by value, but we can still modify what it points to. The pointer is copied, however the copied pointer points to the same object as the original pointer.

Comment: I recommend "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers, Item 31 where this one (and other cases) are deeply explained.

Comment: @R2RT Thanks for the reference definitely I will try to go through that book

Comment: @fefe Does the example make sense

Comment: @HariomSingh You mean your added example? If you change `this->x=10;` to `x=10;`, I think it will illustrate the problem better.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that

```
[=]{ use(i, x); }
```

is in fact

```
[=]{ use(i, this->x); }
```

so we capture `this` and `i` by value, whereas we might wrongly expect that `x` is captured by value.

`[i, this]{ use(i, x); };` is more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried with the example but didn't see any difference.

Because in that example there is no difference in behaviour. However that guideline is here because there is a difference (in the opinion of its authors) in readability.

Consider also

```
auto lambda3 = [i, this]{ use(i, x++); };
```

Comment: That was a very bad example which I created to understand ..can you please suggest a better example which demonstrates the stated behavior

Comment: Thanks for alternative example

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the semantics of the capture aren't obvious from the written syntax. The meaning of the syntax is context dependent, and that can get confusing to read and maintain.

If it was not inside a member function, one would expect `auto lambda = [=]{ use(i, x); };` to make a **copy** of `x`, such that if `x` was to change, the copy would still retain its original value. Calling `lambda` would always call `use(0, 42)`. But it doesn't behave like this inside a member!

You write `=` but instead get behavior that is as if you captured by reference. Code should have one clear and distinct meaning from how it is written.